# finding list of stocks that IPOd since 2010

Tags: stock, yfinance

I am wondering if anyone knows how I can get list of stocks that IPO since 2010. Any suggestions which data source I can use.

Thanks,

DSG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any sources for free. However, I did stumble across this on good old Wikipedia.
It's not a comprehensive list and it has survivorship bias.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:2011_initial_public_offerings

Answer (score 0):

Here are some public sources for IPO data. The data quality varies, especially as you go further back in history, so it's a good idea to check multiple sources:

- [IPOScoop](https://www.iposcoop.com/scoop-track-record-from-2000-to-present/) - contains data from 2000 to present - click the download excel spreadsheet link
- [Nasdaq Market Activity](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/ipos) -  contains data from 1996 to present of Nasdaq and non-Nasdaq IPOs
- [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo) - contains data from 1996 to present